# react-create-app "npm run build" not transpiling JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-scripts

I created a new React project with create-react-app, but when I use `npm run build` and open the resulting build in a browser (served from my own express application), I get console errors about unrecognized JSX syntax that wasn't transpiled.

Is it supposed to do this automatically out of the box or is there something else I need to do?

edit: project structure

```
express-application:
  admin (react build output)
  admin-src (create-react-app project source folder)
  ...
  app.js
  project.json
  gulpfile.js
```

So I use a gulp script to execute `npm run build` in the `admin-src` sub-directory, and then it pipes the resulting build out to `admin`. The `admin` folder is what the application serves as the client.

Comment: What is the file you are opening in the browser?

Comment: @facundo I have automated build scripts to deploy the resulting output folder to my express application which serves the folder. So the index.html from the build is what gets served.

Comment: post your folder structure

Comment: @facundo edited post, I just gave the relevant details

Comment: try `npm start` after building the files.

Comment: @MichaelSorensen I don't want to serve the react application from the `create-react-app` server. For my purpose I need to serve the client from my own application.

Comment: Okay but, does it work when hosted after running `npm start`? Just opening index.html in your browser will not work with CRA.

Comment: @MichaelSorensen Yes, it does appear to work fine when I serve it that way. Also I am not just opening index.html in a browser, I am serving it from a nodejs/express application as a static folder.

Comment: I confess I don't understand your project structure. The app you create with create-react-app you can run it in dev with no need of server, in this case, executing npm start on admin-src path. For building and testing for production you run npm run build , yarn global add serve, serve -s build, also in admin-src path.

Comment: For executing in your server, npm run build and copy the build folder inside admin-src to the folder/path you would like to be served in your server.

Comment: @facundo That's exactly what I've been doing. My gulp script just runs the `npm run build` command and then moves the resulting contents of the admin-src/build folder to the admin folder. What I'm saying is that the JSX in the resulting build folder is not being transpiled down to JS.

Comment: @chrispytoes did you eject the webpack out of CRA? the default webpack that's hidden in CRA uses babel to transpile all the React stuff and I usually leave it alone.

Comment: It will be useful to post the errors to understand better.

Comment: @facundo The error is in the browser: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", which points to JSX that was sent directly to the client.

Comment: Let me understand, your gulp script runs npm run build on react app, copies the build folder , then npm run build  on your express app and finally opens the index file? can you post your gulp script?

Comment: @facundo Not exactly, well I use a vanilla npm script to do `npm run build` on the react project, which after that it will run the gulp task which just pipes out the resulting `build` contents to `admin`. My express app then just serves that folder on localhost. I was actually just changing my gulpfile to use `gulp-jsx` to transpile the JSX on the resulting build myself before moving it, so I'll see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got it working using `gulp` and `gulp-jsx` to transpile the resulting build folder before copying it out.

Here is what I came up with:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const jsx = require('gulp-jsx');

gulp.task('build-admin', () => {
  gulp.src('admin-src/build/**/*!(.js)')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./admin'));
  gulp.src('admin-src/build/**/*.js')
    .pipe(jsx({
      factory: 'React.createClass'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./admin'));
});
```